# How to effective version store procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, version-control

i am part of database development team wotking for big eshop. We are using MS SQL 2016 and ASP.NET. SQL Server is used by clients from 10+ IIS servers using connection pooling (we have aprox 7-10k batch/sec) in production environment and we are using 18 DEV/TESTING IIS servers (but only one DEV database because multi TB size).
We develop a new functionality that forces us to make changes to existing stored procedures quite often.

If we are deploying a change to a production environment, it is a part of changing both the modification of the application to IIS and the change in the database procedures. When deploying, they are always changed to 5 IIS servers, then to 5 more and more. In the meantime, both old and new versions exist on IIS servers. These versions must coexist for some time while using the procedures in the database at the same time. At the database level, we solve this situation by using several versions for the procedure. The old app version calls EXEC dbo.GetProduct, the new app version uses dbo.GetProduct_v2. After you deploy a new version of the application to all IIS, everyone is using dbo.GetProduct_v2. During the next deployment, the situation will be reversed and dbo.GetProduct will contain a new version. A similar situation lies in the development and testing environment.

I fully realize that this solution is not ideal and I would like to be inspired.

We consider separating the data part and the logical part. In one database there will be data tables, other databases will contain only procedures and other program objects. When deploying a new version, we simply deploy a new version of the entire database containing logic and will not need to create a version of the procedure. Procedures from the logic database will query the database with data.
However, the disadvantage of this solution is the impossibility of using natively compiled procedures that we plan to use next year because they do not support querying in other databases.

Another option is using one database and separate procedure versions in different schemas...

If you have any ideas, pros/cons or you know tools what can help us and manage/deploy/use multiple proc versions, please make comment.

Thank you so much

Edit : We are using TFS and Git, but this do not solve versioning of procedures in SQL database. My main question is how to deal with the need to manage multiple versions of IIS applications using multiple versions of the procedures in the database.

Comment: Have you looked into source repositories like GIT? There are multiple other alternatives but thats really what you want to invest in. https://git-scm.com/

Comment: It entertains me when someone asks a question, but their post consists entirely of stating incorrect information about the question. TFS/Git can surely solve the problem of versioning if you use the right projects and tools. Look into Schema Compare.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To not have to change your SP references in your IIS code? And then be able to manage SP versioning in the DB only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Versioning is easy with SSDT or SQL Compare and source control. So are deployments.

Your problem is not versioning.

You need two different stored procedures with the same name, probably same parameters but different code and maybe different results. It's more achievable in, say, .net code because you can use overloading to a point.

Your problem is *phased* deployments using different code:
**Two versions of the same proc must co-exist**.

In your case, I would consider using synonyms to mask the actual stored procedure name.

So you have these stored procedures.

- dbo.GetProduct_v20170926 (last release)
- dbo.GetProduct_v20171012 (this release)
- dbo.GetProduct_v20171025 (next release)
- dbo.GetProduct_v20171113 (one after)

Then you have

```
CREATE SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductBlue FOR dbo.GetProduct_v20171012;
CREATE SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductGreen FOR dbo.GetProduct_v20170926;
```

Your phased IIS deployments refer to one of the SYNONYMNs

Next release...

```
DROP SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductBlue;
CREATE SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductBlue FOR dbo.GetProduct_v20171025;
```

then

```
DROP SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductGreen;
CREATE SYNONYMN dbo.GetProductGreen FOR dbo.GetProduct_v20171113;
```

Using a different schema is the same result but you'd end up with

```
- Blue.GetProduct
- Green.GetProduct
```

Or code your release date into the schema name.

```
- Codev20171025.GetProduct
- Codev20171113.GetProduct
```

You'd have the same problem even you had another set of IIS servers and keep one code base on each set of servers:

Based on the [blue/green deployment model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)

Comment: These feels like pretty much the same thing the OP is already doing, just with 1 further layer of abstraction (the `SYNONYMN`). I could be missing the difference though.

Comment: @thomas: true, it just stabilises the API for the client code, makes it a ittle more obvious which version is in use

Answer (score 1):

A couple assumptions.

- You have a version number in your IIS code somewhere - perhaps an App.config or Web.config file and that version number can be referenced in your .NET code
- Your goal is not to change your IIS .NET SP names on every release but have it call the correct version of the SP in the DB
- All versions of the SP take the same parameters
- Different version of the SP can return different results

Ultimately there is no way around having multiple versions of the stored procedure in the DB. The idea is to abstract that away, as much as possible, from IIS (I am assuming).

Based on the above, I am thinking you could add another parameter to your SP which accepts a version number (which you would likely get from Web.config in IIS).

Then your stored proc `dbo.GetProduct` becomes a "controller" or "routing" stored procedure whose sole purpose is to take the version number and pass the remaining parameters to the appropriate underlying SP.

So you would have 1 SP per version (use whatever naming convention you wish). And `dbo.GetProduct` would call the appropriate one based on the version number passed in. An example is below.

```
create proc dbo.GetProduct_v1 @Param1 int, @Param2 int
as
begin
    --do whatever is needed for v1
    select 1
end

go

create proc dbo.GetProduct_v2 @Param1 int, @Param2 int
as
begin
    --do whatever is needed for v2
    select 2
end

go

create proc dbo.GetProduct @VersionNumber int, @Param1 int, @Param2 int
as
begin
    if @VersionNumber = 1
    begin
        exec dbo.GetProduct_v1 @Param1, @Param2
    end

    if @VersionNumber = 2
    begin
        exec dbo.GetProduct_v2 @Param1, @Param2
    end
end
```

Another thought would be to dynamically build your SP name in IIS (based on the version number in Web.config) instead of hard coding the SP name.